# Json show data from website display only undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wordpress, api

Hallo i have problem with `JSON` to show data on mobile `jQuery`
With console log show everything okay:

```
    $.getJSON("http://www.mcaps.at/redesign/api/get_page/?json=get_page&dev=1&id=119%22",
function page(data) {
 console.log(data.page.content);
});
```

and when I try to display data in div then show me only 19 times undefined 
this is my code to display data:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.mcaps.at/redesign/api/get_page/?json=get_page&dev=1&id=119%22",
 function page(data) {

   var output ='<div>';

   $.each(data.page, function(key,val){

     output+='<p>'+val.content+'</p>';
   });

   output +='</div>';
   $('#home').html(output);


});
```

I need help please!
Thanks!

Comment: Could you please add the JSON your request receives to the question. Also you can remove the `page` identifier from your function declarations as they should be anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop through all the properties:

You can simply use

```
output+='<p>'+data.page.content+'</p>';
```

instead of looping through each property:

```
$.each(data.page, function(key,val){

     output+='<p>'+val.content+'</p>';
   });
```

**DEMO**

```js
$.getJSON("http://www.mcaps.at/redesign/api/get_page/?json=get_page&dev=1&id=119%22",
 function page(data) {

   var output ='<div>';

   

     output+='<p>'+data.page.content+'</p>';
 

   output +='</div>';
   $('#home').html(output);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home"></div>
```

Comment: You should appreciate it by accepting answer or upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `.each`?
Here is the working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cgbte4jf/)